# Why can't I delete a package using NuGet?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, nuget

I installed twitter bootstrap from NuGet, then I figured out I didn't need it anymore. Just for the sake of file size I want to delete this package files from my project folders.

How can I achieve this without deleting important files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Uninstall-Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#Uninstall-Package) command:

> PM> Uninstall-Package Bootstrap [-ProjectName [Uninstall from this project]]

If `ProjectName` parameter is omitted, the default project is chosen. Use the `-Force`
flag to uninstall the package, even if there are dependencies on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, this worked for me but I added -Force:

Uninstall-Package Bootstrap -Force

Comment: @BadaBoom I've corrected my answer, whereas your edit has been rejected by other community members :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

`Uninstall-Package PackageName`

[From Nuget Page](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

The following package elements are removed:

- References in the project. In Solution Explorer, you no longer see the library in the References folder or the bin folder. (You might have to build the project to see it removed from the bin folder.)
- Files in the solution folder. The folder for the package you removed is deleted from the packages folder. If it is the only package you had installed, the packages folder is also deleted.)
- Any changes that were made to your app.config or web.config file are undone.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to the command-line via the visual studio interface you can do the following:

- Right-click the references folder
- Select 'manage nuget packages'
- Select 'installed packages'
- Select the package you want to uninstall
- Press the 'Uninstall button'.